# How do I set the value of an element within a directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm working a directive to autotab between elements whenever the element's maxLength is hit.  But first, I'm trying to figure out how to make sure that an element can't have a value whose length is greater than the element's maxlength.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
  if (el.value.length >= el.maxLength) {
    el.value = el.value.substr(0, el.maxLength);
  }
```

If I set a breakpoint and step through it, right after executing this, `el.value` is being set correctly, but in the view it's still allowing the user to type.

Comment: Wouldn't the `maxLength` attribute restrict the value length, why do you need this condition `el.value.length >= el.maxLength`?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10">`

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically modifying validator attributes is currently not supported. They have to be statically added (no `[]` binding) and are only read once when the control instance is built.

You can do this with forms using `FormBuilder` and a validator that has a reference to other values that might influence the validation like shown in [How to change validation of a control after it has been initiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852315/how-to-change-validation-of-a-control-after-it-has-been-initiated/37852441#37852441)

Comment: I don't really consider this a validator though, I'm just trying to force a value

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800841/input-mask-fields-in-angular2-forms Your question is not clear enough to me to make better suggestions

Comment: I'm not sure how I can clarify it.  Whenever the user types in an input, I'm checking if the input's value's length is greater than the input's maxlength.  If it is, I want to truncate the input's value to match the maxlength.  So if I  have a field whose maxlength is 5, the user can't type more than 5 characters.

In jQuery, I would have done `$("#element").val($("#element").val().substr(0,maxlength))`

Comment: Sounds like the approach in the linked question should fit.

Comment: Hm, yeah, I think it might be.  I'll check it out now.  Thanks!

Comment: You can add an `@Input()maxLength;` to get the setting from the element.